# How to display recording time in Android?

Tags: android, audio, recording

I developed a sound record application for Android that is working fine. Now I want to display the recording time in a `TextView`. How can I implement it?

Answer (score 7):

**Use CountDownTimer Because when you record at that time may be TimerTask not work , as per my knowledge**

```
CountDownTimer t;

t = new CountDownTimer( Long.MAX_VALUE , 1000) {

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            cnt++;
            String time = new Integer(cnt).toString();

            long millis = cnt;
               int seconds = (int) (millis / 60);
               int minutes = seconds / 60;
               seconds     = seconds % 60;

               txtcount.setText(String.format("%d:%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds,millis));

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {            }
    };
```

**Start timer t.start(); 
Stop timer  t.cancel();**

Answer (score 2):

Use `android.widget.Chronometer` to record time.

See `com.example.android.apis.view.ChronometerDemo` in ApiDemos for usage.

Answer (score 1):

When you start recording start the timer

Here is the code 
    int minute =0, seconds = 0, hour = 0;

```
textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
final Timer t = new Timer("hello", true);
t.schedule(new TimerTask() {

@Override
public void run() {
    textView.post(new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        seconds++;
        if (seconds == 60) {
        seconds = 0;
        minute++;
        }
        if (minute == 60) {
        minute = 0;
        hour++;
        }
        textView.setText(""
            + (hour > 9 ? hour : ("0" + hour)) + " : "
            + (minute > 9 ? minute : ("0" + minute))
            + " : "
            + (seconds > 9 ? seconds : "0" + seconds));

    }
    });

    }
    }, 1000, 1000);

    view.findViewById(R.id.stop).setOnClickListener(
    new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        t.cancel();
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Timer and TimerTask in android.
check here ...http://android.okhelp.cz/timer-task-timertask-run-cancel-android-example/